# Archiving data in spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have implemented a time booking system based on spreadsheets which the users fill out and then are consolidated into one central (and big) spreadsheet.

After having had a few performance issues the whole application now runs perfectly since several months. However, I will soon run into the size limitation of spreadsheets (400k cells).

In the consolidated spreadsheet I basically do not need more data than the current month. However for statistical purposes I would appreciate if I could make the data easily accessible for the domains users.

Basically the BigQuery Service would be perfect but I did not find an API to write data to it from a spreadsheet. I hesitate to use the Google provided MySQL database for cost reasons.

Are there any other ideas around?

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in Google BigQuery API for Apps Scripts, you just have to enable it manually under `Resources > Use Google APIs`. There's also Fusion Tables, that does not have a built-in API but is somewhat simple to use via `UrlFetch`.

Anyway, if it's statistical purposes, why don't you just "compile" the data in another spreadsheet? e.g. `month - amount of entries - total prices - avg etc - etc...`